# palindrome , can't return False for no string

Tags: python, python-2.7

A palindrome is a word, phrase, number or other sequence of units that can be read the same way in either direction. Write a function that determines whether the given word or number is a palindrome.

**Examples**

```
>>> isPalindrome("")
False
>>> isPalindrome("Racecar")
True
>>> isPalindrome(121)
True
>>> isPalindrome("Never")
False
>>> isPalindrome("level")
True
```

**MY Code**

```
def isPalindrome(word):
        word = str(word)
        if word == ''.join(reversed(word)) :
            return True
        elif len(word)<1 or word[0] == '':
            return False
        else: 
            return False
    print isPalindrome('')
    print isPalindrome('abba')
    print isPalindrome('level')
    print isPalindrome(12321)
```

**what this code returning is.**

```
True
True
True
True
```

where as it should return false for  >>> isPalindrome(""), but it's returning True, so what should i do change in my code to make it correct., withe other condition the code working is fine.

Comment: first you need to check `if len(word)<1 or word[0] == '':` this condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    word = str(word)
    if word and word == ''.join(reversed(word)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This returns `True` only if `word` is true and `word == ''.join(reversed(word))` is true.  A string is true only if it is non-empty.  This eliminates the need for the test `len(word)<1`.

Incidentally, the test `word[0] == ''` will likely not do what you expect: if `word` is empty, then `word[0]` will throw an `IndexError`.

#### Still simpler

Based on a suggestion by BrianO:

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    word = str(word)
    return bool(word) and word == word[::-1]
```

Comment: word=str(word) is actually needed since he also checks integer data

Comment: @VigneshKalai Good eyes.  Yes, you are right: the last example does not have quotes.

Comment: Awesome answer though :D

Comment: Simpler still:

`def isPalindrome(word):   word = str(word);     return word and word == word[::-1]`
Actually, I disagree with returning `False` for the empty string, because it too is a palindrome, but I guess that's what the assignment requires ;)

Comment: @BrianO Excellent.  I had to make one minor tweak: I replaced `return word and word == word[::-1]` with `return bool(word) and word == word[::-1]` in order that `isPalindrome('')` returns `False` not `''`.

Comment: Darn, you're right, and good catch - `'' and anything` evaluates to `''` not `False`. Of course, this is unnecessary using the correct definition of "palindrome". (lol)

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the word is empty at first itself :

```
def isPalindrome(word):
        word = str(word)
        if len(word)<1 or word[0] == '':
            return False
        if word == ''.join(reversed(word)) :
            return True


        return False

print isPalindrome('')
print isPalindrome('abba')
print isPalindrome('level')
print isPalindrome(12321)
print isPalindrome(1231)
```

**output:**

```
False
True
True
True
False
```

This is due to the fact that your first if case will be true if the given word is empty string

**i.e)**

```
word= ''    
word == ''.join(reversed(word))         
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement is causing the empty string to return true and exit the function.

You need to switch your if and else if statements.